# Why am I getting $2i\pi = 0$?

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

We know $\ln (-1)$ is $i\pi$ which can be found in the following way:
$$
e^{i\pi} = \cos\pi \ +  \ i\sin\pi = -1 \\ \implies \ln e^{i\pi} = \ln(-1)\implies \ln(-1) = i\pi
$$
In the similar way, we can write:
$$
e^{2i\pi} = \cos2\pi \ + \ i\sin2\pi = 1 \\ \implies \ln(e^{2i\pi}) = \ln(1) \implies 2i\pi = 0
$$
What is wrong here?

Comment: The complex $\log$ is a multi-valued function.

Comment: When the input is a complex number, the function $f(z)=e^z$ is periodic with period $2\pi i$. So the complex logarithm is "multiple valued" i.e. can add $2 \pi i$ to anything and get the same logarithm.

Comment: For a discussion of the multi-valued-ness of the complex logarithm, see ["Problems with inverting the complex exponential function"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Problems_with_inverting_the_complex_exponential_function) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike real numbers, non-zero complex numbers $z$ have infinitely many logarithms i.e. numbers $w$ such that $e^w=z$. The principal value generally accepted (denoted $\mathrm{Log}$) doesn't satisfy $\mathrm{Log}(e^a)=a$ for every $a\in\mathbb C$. Instead, for every $r\in\mathbb R_+^*$ and $\theta\in\mathbb R$, $$\mathrm{Log} (re^{i\theta})=\mathrm{ln}(r)+i(\theta \text{ mod } 2\pi)$$
with $(\theta \text{ mod } 2\pi)\in[-\pi,\pi)$.