How is this argument that $0=i2\pi n$ incorrect?
I was messing around with some algebra until I came across this:
$$0=\ln(1)=\ln(e^{i2\pi n})=i2\pi n,n\in \mathbb{Z}$$
The entire thing seems entirely justified, but I don't understand why it's like this. If anyone could point out an error here, that would be nice.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4185112/42969 and the linked questions.

Thanks! I didn't realize that it was already a posted question.

Complex log is not injective

You have a periodic function under the logarithm.
